# How to bring same layout for all pages in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to ask how to make all pages with same layout in laravel. I try to do it by follow some tutorial in google. It bring the layout but display the content at top of the header and if i add `@endsection` it hide the content. I hope anyone can help me to solve the problem.

Below i attach the code.

**layout**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
    @include('admin.header.header')
    @include('admin.sidebar.sidebar')
  <section id="container" class=""> 
   @yield('content')
  </section>
</body>
</body>
```

**Content page (member)**

```
@extends('admin.layout')
@section('content')
    i am the home page
@endsection
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/member', function () {
   return view('member');
});
```

Comment: Your code should work. 
Just for testing, try to do @include('content.page') in your layouts file, instead of @yield. Does that work?

Comment: Except for the double `</body>` this looks ok (unless you have some weird stuff going on in your `admin.header.header` and `admin.sidebar.sidebar`. The Laravel docs also have a [section on layouts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade)

Comment: Does the member.blade.php exists at the root level of resources/views?

Also a blank page might mean you have no write/read permissions on your storage/logs folder

Answer (score 1):

use @stop instead @endsection

```
@extends('admin.layout')
@section('content')
i am the home page
@stop
```